# Issue with generating list of dictionary using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
feed_mapping = {'BC': 11, 'HA':12, 'AB':16,'GR':18}
x = ['AB-16007891', 'HA-4625798','GR-4444545','BC-4447764','HA-46257854']
feed = [{"feed": feed_mapping[i.split('-')[0]],"id":[i]} for i in x]
print(feed)
```

With this above list comprehension, I can generate the list of dictionary.**I need to append the values to `id` if the `feed`value is same**

**Current Output:**

```
[{'feed': 16, 'id': ['AB-16007891']}, {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-4625798']}, {'feed': 18, 'id': ['GR-4444545']}, {'feed': 11, 'id': ['BC-4447764']}, {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-46257854']}]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[{'feed': 16, 'id': ['AB-16007891']}, {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-4625798','HA-46257854']}, {'feed': 18, 'id': ['GR-4444545']}, {'feed': 11, 'id': ['BC-4447764']}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby
feed_mapping = {'BC': 11, 'HA':12, 'AB':16,'GR':18}
x = ['AB-16007891', 'HA-4625798','GR-4444545','BC-4447764','HA-46257854']
x.sort()

feed = [{"feed": feed_mapping[k], "id": list(v)} for k, v in groupby(x, lambda x: x.split('-')[0])]
print(feed)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'feed': 16, 'id': ['AB-16007891']},
 {'feed': 11, 'id': ['BC-4447764']},
 {'feed': 18, 'id': ['GR-4444545']},
 {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-46257854', 'HA-4625798']}]
```

Comment: You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using lambda, please note that this solution does not keep the same order as in your question:

```
feed_mapping = {'BC': 11, 'HA': 12, 'AB': 16, 'GR': 18}
x = ['AB-16007891', 'HA-4625798', 'GR-4444545', 'BC-4447764', 'HA-46257854']
feed = [{"feed": feed_value, "id": [i for i in x if feed_key in i]} for
        feed_key, feed_value in feed_mapping.items()]
print(feed)

>>> [{'feed': 11, 'id': ['BC-4447764']}, {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-4625798', 'HA-46257854']}, {'feed': 16, 'id': ['AB-16007891']}, {'feed': 18, 'id': ['GR-4444545']}]
```

I split up you key and value from feed_mapping using the following for loop:

```
for feed_key, feed_value in feed_mapping.items()]
```

Then I have a second (nested for loop to add items in `x` to the `id` field:

```
i for i in x
```

I noticed that you only want to add an id if the `feed_mapping` key is in the string of `i`, which I do using the following if statement within the nested for loop:

```
[i for i in x if feed_key in i]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list `x` into a dictionary using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

feed_mapping = {'BC': 11, 'HA':12, 'AB':16,'GR':18}
x = ['AB-16007891', 'HA-4625798','GR-4444545','BC-4447764','HA-46257854']

x_ = defaultdict(list)
for i in x:
    key = i.split('-')[0]
    x_[key].append(i)

[{'feed': feed_mapping[k], 'id': v} for k, v in x_.items()]
# [{'feed': 16, 'id': ['AB-16007891']}, {'feed': 12, 'id': ['HA-4625798', 'HA-46257854']}, {'feed': 18, 'id': ['GR-4444545']}, {'feed': 11, 'id': ['BC-4447764']}]
```